# Ignite Queue Persistence

Tags: ignite

I'm looking for persistence configuration in IgniteQueue, but couldn't find any useful documents. In Collectionconfiguration there is no option for DataRegion. Is there any way to persists IgniteQueue to solve dataloss problem ?.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Data structures are created in the default data region, so in order to make `IgniteQueue` persisted you need to make the default data region persisted using [DataStorageConfiguration#setDefaultDataRegionConfiguration](https://ignite.apache.org/releases/latest/javadoc/org/apache/ignite/configuration/DataStorageConfiguration.html#setDefaultDataRegionConfiguration-org.apache.ignite.configuration.DataRegionConfiguration-)

There is also a JIRA ticket for making it possible to specify a data region for structures: https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/IGNITE-6820
Nobody seems to be interested in fixing it though.